# How to compare two dataframes and add new flag column in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have created two data frames by executing below command.

```
test1 = sc.parallelize([
    ("a",1,1),
    ("b",2,2),
    ("d",4,2),
    ("e",4,1),
    ("c",3,4)]).toDF(['SID','SSection','SRank'])
test1.show()
+---+--------+-----+
|SID|SSection|SRank|
+---+--------+-----+
|  a|       1|    1|
|  b|       2|    2|
|  d|       4|    2|
|  e|       4|    1|
|  c|       3|    4|
+---+--------+-----+

test2=sc.parallelize([
    ("a",1,1),
    ("b",2,3),
    ("f",4,2),
    ("e",4,1),
    ("c",3,4)]).toDF(['SID','SSection','SRank'])
test2.show()
+---+--------+-----+
|SID|SSection|SRank|
+---+--------+-----+
|  a|       1|    1|
|  b|       2|    3|
|  f|       4|    2|
|  e|       4|    1|
|  c|       3|    4|
+---+--------+-----+
```

using test1 and test2 data-frames I need to produce new dataframe which should contain result like below .

```
+---+--------+----------+------------+------------+
|SID|SSection|test1SRank|test2SRank  |      flag  |
+---+--------+----------+------------+------------+
|  a|       1|    1     |       1    | same_rank  |
|  b|       2|    2     |       3    |rank_changed|
|  d|       4|    2     |       0    |No_rank     |
|  e|       4|    1     |       1    |same_rank   |
|  c|       3|    4     |       4    |same_rank   |
|  f|       4|    0     |       2    |new_rank    |
+---+--------+----------+------------+------------+
```

above result I want to produce by comparison between test1 and test2  data frames using combination of columns `SID` and `SSection` and comparison between `ranks`.

for example :

1) SID `(a)` and SSection `(1)`: in test1rank is`1` and test2rank is `1` so my flag value  should be `same_rank`.

2) SID `(b)` and SSection `(2)`: in test1rank is `2` and test2rank is `3` here rank was changed so my flag value should be `rank_changed`.

3) SID `(d)` and SSection `(4)`: in test1rank is `2` and in test2rank he lost his rank, so my flag value should be `No_rank`
4) SID `(f)` and SSection `(4)`: in test1rank is he was not performed well so he don't have any rank and in test2rank he performed well his rank is 2, so my flag value should be `New_rank`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you what you want:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

test3=test1.withColumnRenamed('SRank','test1SRank')\
    .join(test2.drop('SSection')\
    .withColumnRenamed('SRank','test2SRank'), on='SID', how='outer')\
    .fillna(0)

test3=test3.withColumn('flag', f.expr("case when test1SRank=0 and test2SRank>0 then 'new_rank'\
                                            when test1SRank>0 and test2SRank=0 then 'No_rank'\
                                            when test1SRank=test2SRank then 'same_rank'\
                                            else 'rank_changed' end"))
test3.orderBy('SID').show()
```

Explanation: Outer join the data frame so you have test1 and test2 scores for all SIDs. Then fill nulls with 0 and perform the flag logic with a sql case when statement.

Comment: thanks for quick reply :),  but i am getting error like NameError: name 'f' is not defined

Comment: sorry my omission, will modify answer

Comment: ok added the import statement for functions, let me know if this works now

Comment: great! glad to hear it

Comment: suppose if i want achieve same thing in UDF.. How can I achieve

Comment: if you mean the flag logic, you could create a python function that takes test1SRank and test2SRank as arguments and implements the equivalent of the sql, then wrap into a udf. However, on large data sets the sql will be faster

Comment: hi suppose my test2 like this "test2=sc.parallelize([
    ("a",2,1),
    ("b",2,3),
    ("f",4,2),
    ("e",4,1),
    ("c",3,4)]).toDF(['SID','SSection','SRank'])" ..it is not working.please  help me on this ..thanks in advance .

Comment: we are dropping the test2.drop('SSection') , it is not expected because if your dropping  we will miss "row SID = F " and SSection value we are getting 0.that is  not expected .please help me on this